# Will editing a title of the question result in a broken link?

Tags: support, edits, hyperlinks, title

If I was to edit the title of a question and someone was to accept the edit, would the question link become broken?  Or would it redirect to the new link?

I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87212/i-dont-think-so`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87212/i-dont-think-so)

Comment: To clarify a bit, the only thing that matters is the question ID which comes before the "title" in the URL.. change it, and you break the link..

Comment: wtf just happened to that link... o___o

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160343/Unicorns!